# What is DJ's actual name?

Tags: star-wars, names, the-last-jedi

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177855/3823) points out that DJ's hat bears an emblem that reads **DON'T JOIN**.

[image]

So clearly, out-of-universe, *DJ* derives from that expression.

But in universe, is *Don't Join* a backronym from his actual name *DJ*? Or is *DJ* a nickname derived from the expression? If it is a nickname, what is his birth name? And does he have any other aliases?

Comment: Yes, DJ is a nick name refering to a belief: "Don't Join" (pointing out his freelancing/self interest ways), but so far, I haven't come across any media [yet] that established what his real name is. Here's a link about what is known: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DJ

Comment: You're missing the important part.  If you figure out his name, you can figure out who his parents are?  I'm betting Skywalker.

Comment: @kaine - I'm betting that it's a family name and that his father is actually [*Jaz'i J'eph*](https://tinyurl.com/pypppmp)

Answer (score 19):

The [Last Jedi: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) answers a couple of your sub-questions, namely that his nickname DJ derives from the initials of the words on his hat.

> **DON'T JOIN**
>
> DJ has little that passes as a personal ethos, save for **the two
>   words that are the source of his nickname: DON'T JOIN.** He thinks
>   larger causes are for fools, since society is just a machine looking
>   to turn everyone into cog. First Order,  Resistance or New Republic -
>   it doesn't matter where on the spectrum such a cause may lie,
>   ultimately all are meat grinders that chew up their followers with the
>   same disinterest.

As to his real (given) name, that's not been confirmed or revealed.

Answer (score 7):

In universe, no name is ever given for this character. He is only referred to as the slicer or code breaker. We know of no other names or aliases for this character right now.

Out of universe, DJ is derived from the expression. Though it should be clear that it was derived by Lucasfilm and not the general public as [Benicio Del Toro was credited as "DJ" in the film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/). Given that this is the case, it could be his in-universe moniker in Episode 9 or the novelization. Though this remains to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

> "It's all a machine, partner. Live free, don't join."

**It's unlcear** if "DJ" is *only* a nickname or acronym refering to his philosophy, "Don't Join" or if it also does or does not coincide with his yet to be revealed real name. But the following does substantuate the "Don't Join" philosophy:

> DJ's an exceptional slicer and unscrupulous thief, DJ always marauded in
>   the shadows at Canto Bight, frequently stealing the things he
>   needed.[1] He could effortlessly pick the lock to a jail cell[6] or
>   open a sealed door by using a piece of gold.[2] **According to DJ's
>   personal philosophy, the only way to live a free existence was to not
>   choose a side.** He was resolute in his opinions and refused to join the
>   First Order or the Resistance as their rivalry escalated into open
>   war.[1] **He regarded neither side as good or evil,[2] believing that
>   both factions were part of a system built on greed and corruption.**[1]
>
> Although he refused to join a side in the conflict,[1] DJ was capable
>   of working with either faction **if it suited his interests.** He helped
>   the Resistance in their attempt to disable General Hux's tracking
>   system, but ultimately turned against them by cooperating with the
>   First Order in return for his life and the compensation of a
>   reward.[2] To bind one's self to any cause, DJ believed, would
>   ultimately lead to their downfall.[7]
>
> DJ was a human male[1] with black hair, brown eyes, and tan skin.[2]
>   His philosophy—**encapsulated in the motto "DON'T JOIN"—was etched into
>   a plate adorning his hat.** http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DJ

**Things to consider:**
It should be noted that he is never actually called "DJ" throughout the course of *The Last Jedi*, but the initials first appeared on The Cap of the character's [Funko Pop](https://movieweb.com/star-wars-last-jedi-benicio-del-toro-character-dj-what-it-means/) and then also in the film.

If one would think deeper and take the cap more seriously,  the concept of having those initials on a piece of clothing, is ironic, as someone who cares about **wealth distribution** by believing that all major players are greedy and corrupt, would "advertise" (or somewhat corporately promote) "Don't Join" on their person. It could then make one wonder, if there *is* an "organization" behind "Don't Join" and this is a hint rather than irony?

Comment: Sounds like an organization of anarchists, which sounds self-defeating, but there really are such groups.

Comment: @Wildcard Ya, I mean if there are, it does seem monstly self defeating, except to say that there could be goal to try and dismantel the two big sides to try and spread the money around, but unless someone is leaning towards Utopia-Communism, you're probably always going to have some kind of class system. In any case, It would be nice if "DJ" would evolve to find his mind changed though...

Comment: I'm sure they think of themselves as enlightened rebels against the system, but when one faction goes around *murdering entire planets* it **might** be time to consider the possibility of a bit of nuance in your jaded cynical both-siderism.

Comment: Before the name DJ was revealed, and with Gugu Mbatha Raw in the running, the thought crossed my mind BDT could of been playing Kes Dameron--if that were somehow true and something happened to Shara Bay in a later conflict--I could Kes not being thrilled about either side.